# How to solve the limit: $a_n=\frac{4-e^n}{6+5e^{n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$a_n=\frac{4-e^n}{6+5e^{n+1}}$$

As $a_n$ approaches infinity

Since there is euler number in here, it really confuses me...

Comment: The limit of what? $a_n$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$? Be more specific please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use substitution: set $x=\mathrm e^n$, and rewrite the fraction as
$$\frac{4-\mathrm e^{n}}{6+5\mathrm e^{n+1}}=\frac{4-x}{6+5\mathrm e\,x},$$
which tends to $\;-\dfrac1{5\mathrm e}\;$ as $x$ tends to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Divide to and bottom by $e^{n}$ to obtain:

$$\frac{4e^{-n}-1}{6e^{-n}+5e}$$

As $n\rightarrow\infty$, you know that $e^{-n}\rightarrow 0$